# reloadData is only refreshing one row

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a grouped tableView of 4 rows.  I did a pretty big overhaul on how I am doing things between two views and now reloadData is acting weird.  It will only refresh the data in one row. (the last one) and none of the others.

I have checked my values in my viewDidAppear method (where I call reloadData) and all my values are updated.

The code..

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   // reload the table data
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
   // Set up the cell...
  static NSString *CellWithIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [_tableGroup.options objectAtIndex:rowcount];
    cell.tag = rowcount;
    rowcount++;

    //label for currently selected/saved setting
    _currentSetting = [[BaseLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 8, 115, 25)];
    [_currentSetting setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    _currentSetting.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _currentSetting.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _currentSetting.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
}

if (cell.tag == 0) {
    _currentSetting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ mi",[settings.val1 stringValue]];

}
else if(cell.tag == 1)
{
    _currentSetting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ items",[settings.val2 stringValue]];

}
else if(cell.tag == 2) 
{
    _currentSetting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ items",[settings.val3 stringValue]];

}

[cell.contentView addSubview:_currentSetting];

return cell;
}
```

I've gone through with NSLog and everything is getting called as it should on reloadData, but the cells aren't changing their labels.  Why?

Comment: ugh, so many problems in so short code.

Comment: It's obvious you don't understand what should this method do and how `UITableView` works. Please, refer to Apple tutorials.

Comment: Regarding your edit - it's not true. All the answers get directly to the point. You are using the table incorrectly and it won't never work that way. You are getting some random behavior and we can't help you to solve that until you solve the original issue. We told you how to do it correctly... and that's the only way how to do it. You are saying you can't do it that way because... something. Maybe you should show us how your data looks like and we will show you how to use them in a table.

Answer (score 3):

The major problem I can see here is this :

```
cell.tag = rowcount;
rowcount++;
```

cell.tag must not be present inside **if (cell == nil)**, you should rather take it out. Instead you shouldn't be checking cell.tag to set currentSettingText at all, you should be using indexPath.row

Also in each viewDidAppear,when you reload The Table, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, which is incrementing rowCount and hence cell.tag everytime, where are you resetting it?

Comment: can't use indexPath.row  in a grouped table all new groups reset their  first rows to zero.

Comment: and that does absolutely nothing to give me the value i need. all of my rows are passed in an array, and all of the groups come in as a separate array.  i have to pull out the rows in order based on the array and can't do that when index path resets to zero every group

Comment: @JesseDurham If I understand you and your code correctly - 3 rows in every group, the index into the data array is just a simple callucation `section * 3 + row`. Also, you are claiming you have only 4 rows so you can even hardcode it... Where is the problem?

Comment: the number of groups and number of rows is dynamic and completely dependent on whatever is passed into my class.  i have no way of knowing the exact amount, it just so happens this test case has 3 groups, 2 have one row, and one has two rows.

Comment: Then you have to fix how your data is stored. If you are displaying rows of data in groups, save the data differently so that the connection between the group and the data exist even in the data model, not just in UI.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1:**  cellForRowAtIndexPath needs to return a cell, either by getting an existing cell, or by creating one and adding a subview (only when it creates a cell).  When we have an existing cell, we can assume it has the subview added, so we just go looking for it.  So it will work like this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     

    static NSString *CellWithIdentifier = @"Cell";
    BaseLabel *_currentSetting;

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        // new cell, so add a label
        _currentSetting = [[BaseLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 8, 115, 25)];
        [_currentSetting setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
        _currentSetting.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _currentSetting.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        _currentSetting.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        _currentSetting.tag = 128;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_currentSetting];
    } else {
        // existing cell so find the label
        _currentSetting = (BaseLabel *)[cell viewWithTag:128];
    }
```

**Problem 2:**  Now we have a cell ready to go and a handle to a label subview, how should it be configured?  The only sensible way is to look into our model based on the indexPath.

Here's where I can't help much without understanding the model, but the generic idea is this:

```
    // say my model is an array of N arrays, one for each section, I would do this
    NSArray *sectionModel = [self.mainModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    id *modelElement = [sectionModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // now configure the cell based on modelElement
    _currentSetting.text = [modelElement someStringAttributeOfMyModel];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: +1 For the patience to remake the code into something sensible.

Comment: what exactly is self.mainModel ?

Comment: Ok, i edited my changes to adopt indexpath.section etc etc, did all the stuff you guys said was so broken.  My original problem still exists.

Comment: @JesseDurham please post the edit.  also post where you define your model.  mainModel is a made-up model to stand in generically for your model.

Answer (score 1):

I can overlook the `viewWillAppear` call in `viewDidAppear` which is very strange but what is interesting is that you don't use the `indexPath` parameter in you method at all.
Since this parameter is the only way how to check which cell you are generating, you can get practically any result and the cells can be ordered randomly. A `reloadData` will just shuffle them again.

As the `rowcount` only increases, very soon none of your `cell.tag ==` comparisons will evaluate to true.

By the way, the code is adding subviews to already existing cells - that means that after several reloads or some scrolling your cells will have many labels. Why you save the last label added to a cell into an instance variable, change it text and then move it to a different cell... that's a mystery.

**Your code doesn't have any sense!**

Comment: ha, that view will appear call in view did appear was actually an error from the copy/paste over.